# Routing URLs between Django and Angular

Tags: django, angular, url, static, lazy-loading

I'm currently creating a website in Django and Angular. Django is serving the Angular build files. Excluding `/api` calls, all URLs are returned a template that loads the Angular index. This part works.

The part I'm having trouble with is when I try to lazy-load modules. Angular will try to find a module `foo` at `localhost:8000/foo-module.js`, but it's really at `localhost:8000/static/mydjangoapp/angular/foo-module.js`.

I know I could solve this problem by setting `<base href="/" />` in `index.html` to `<base href="/static/mydjangoapp/angular" />`, but I want the frontend to be served from `/`. I could also avoid lazy-loading modules, but I feel like there's a better way to serve Angular from Django using which I can lazy-load.

How can I get Angular to properly fetch the URLs? I'm also having a similar issue with serving Angular assets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack Code Splitting 'Loading chunk failed' error wrong file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704950/webpack-code-splitting-loading-chunk-failed-error-wrong-file-path)

Comment: Yup, thanks! If you post it as as an answer I'll accept it.