# Chrome 85 on Android 10 breaks PWA?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Recently I have noticed that my PWA is no longer working on my Chrome 85.0.4183.127 on Android 10.
I use code splitting using React lazy() load and Webpack 4.

When navigating to a lazy loaded resource my installed PWA on Android 10 reports

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(missing: https://example.com/0.bundle.js)
```

The location for the 0.bundle.js in the above error message is ***incorrect***. The correct path `/dist/0.bundle.js` is defined in  `index.js` and `serviceWorker.js` but Chrome seems to be looking in the root.
I have cleared the cache and updated the service worker to no avail.

When installing the PWA on my desktop computer (Windows 10 x64) - Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit) all is fine! The resources loads as expected!

How can I remedy this problem?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post containing the solution to my problem:
[Webpack Code Splitting 'Loading chunk failed' error wrong file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704950/webpack-code-splitting-loading-chunk-failed-error-wrong-file-path)

In conclusion:

> That happens because output.publicPath by default is /. Just update
> [the webpack.config.js option] output.publicPath to point where you
> want it to be => /dist/.

Updating the output.publicPath in webpack.config.js solved my problem! Now the site and PWA works as expected!

A good practice seems to be to ***always include*** `output.publicPath` in your config to prevent possible problems.
Kind regards /K