# Reactjs missing files when running `npm run build`

Tags: reactjs

Why is it when i run `npm run build` in reactjs i encounter missing files?

[image]

this is the error i get

[image]

[image]

jsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "/"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

UPDATE

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "changelog": "auto-changelog --starting-version 3.0.0 --commit-limit false --hide-credit"
  },
```

Comment: what is the directory you are firing the command ?

Comment: inside my visual studio there is terminal that connects to my application

Comment: check the current directory you're running the command.

Comment: I updated the question with image, please see

Comment: run ```npm i``` and then ```npm run build```

Comment: I receive this error when running npm i

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235263/discussion-between-kaito-and-therakeshpurohit).

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697927/chunkloaderror-loading-chunk-xy-failed-randomly-getting-fatal-on-production)